# Azure WebJob and instance async method

Tags: c#, delegates, async-await, azure-webjobs

I want to use Dependency Injection in my azure web job. For it I have to make class and method as non-static:

```
   public class Functions
    {
        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public async Task GetDriversAsync(TextWriter logger)
        {

        }

        [NoAutomaticTrigger]
        public void Test()
        {
        }
    }
```

then I want to pass it to Call method of JobHost object.

I try to do this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var config = new JobHostConfiguration();

        if (config.IsDevelopment)
        {
            config.UseDevelopmentSettings();
        }

        var host = new JobHost(config);

        Functions f = new Functions();

        host.Call(((Action)f.Test).Method);
        host.Call(((Action)f.GetDriversAsync).Method);
    }
}
```

with synchronous method it works fine, by try to do it `((Action)f.GetDriversAsync).Method` I get a compilation error:

> Cannot convert type 'method' to 'Action'

How to write that line correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use ordinary synchronous methods.
If you look into [source code](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/JobHost.cs), you will find that the host invokes the methods asynchronously. Or you can call `CallAsync` to wait for the task.

And if I found the correct [executor](https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/blob/5140983cb163b20bf6af60afccebb705bc80ad80/src/Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host/Executors/FunctionExecutor.cs), you don't have to worry that your method would be called in the async/await way.

So just don't cast your method to an Action. Instead,

```
host.Call(typeof(Functions).GetMethod("GetDriversAsync"));
```

Comment: it works, thank you. But why, we don't create an instance of Functions?

Comment: @OlegSh look into executor. It creates the instance.